# How to run a hadoop hdfs testcase from terminal

Tags: testing, hadoop, hdfs

After importing hadoop hdfs project into intellij idea, a test could be run easily, to run TestINodeFile, just right-click the test a select Run TestINodeFile.

Is there a way I can run it from terminal ? Like mvn -Dtest=TestINodeFile or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out mrunit which allow you to unit test map reduce jobs. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MRUNIT/MRUnit+Tutorial